# Error accesing published WS proxy in WSO2 ESB 4.6: EPR not found

Tags: wso2-esb

I deployed exactly the same WS-proxy in 4.5.1 and 4.6. With 4.5.1 it works correctly, but with 4.6 I get:

```
ERROR - AxisEngine The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/registro.registroHttpSoap11Endpoint and the WSA Action = . If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
```

The source is the following:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="registro" transports="http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
  <target>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <endpoint>
      <address uri="http://localhost:15080/SIGEM_RegistroPresencialWS/services/ServicioRegistroWebService"/>
    </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:15080/SIGEM_RegistroPresencialWS/services/ServicioRegistroWebService?wsdl"/>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

What do I have to do for 4.6. to make it work?

Thanx.

Comment: Comparing the exact requests with ngrep I can observe that my client (python suds) uses soap1.1 endpoint but sends a SOAPAction "". The "Try it" client sends the correct SOAPAction for SOAP 1.1 Endpoint, and no SOAPAction form SOAP 1.2 Endpoint. May be that this is a suds issue, but using with 4.5.1 it works and directly too. May it be a WSDL issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enhance ESB performance pass-through transport has been enabled by default starting from  ESB 4.6.0 version that is not the case for ESB 4.5.1. It seems your proxy service depends on SOAP body based dispatching but pass-through transport does not support for SOAP body based dispatching. SOAP body based dispatching build the message body and use first element's local name for dispatching which effect to proxy performance badly that is the reason it was not supported in pass-through transport. We are in a process to fix this limitation for future ESB releasees without loosing any advantage of pass-through transport.

BTW for the moment you can use one of the following workarounds.

1. When sending a messages to the proxy service append operation name to the endpoint URL

   e.g - `http://serverName/app/serviceName/operationName`
2. Modify client level code to send expected SOAPAction value ( like Try-It case)
3. I'm not sure your backend service's WSDL defined "" as the value of SOAPAction if that is the case you may modified the backend  service to have value other than "" per each operation. AS an example for JAX-WS services you can use @WebMethod annotation for this.

e.g - @WebMethod(action="XXXX")

Note : In case if your backend WSDL defining a value other than "" for SOAPAction while your client send message with SOAPAction="" then it's a violation of service contract by the client and need to be fixed on client level.

Comment: I did 2., and it works correctly. 

1. Also seems to be a good solution to me, although I have to change location for each operation. This may require to use a SOAP client instance for each different operation I use (which is suboptimal). 

For 3., I can't change the original product which uses empty SOAPActions as you state in 3., but I could publish a custom WSDL with SOAPActions.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem with wso2 ESB 4.7 and the web service is also developed by me for the company.

What worked for me is adding **soapAction** attribute to wsdl **soap:operation** element like below.

```
<soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/services/hello" style="document"/>
```