# SOAP-request isn't dispatched by QName of the first body child element

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a service described with this [WSDL](http://pastebin.com/8BUStH03). When its operation `createService` is invoked with this [request](http://pastebin.com/b0FBHwSC) everything is fine. For this service a proxy service has been made on WSO2 ESB 4.6.0. [Here](http://pastebin.com/ccWjNvz0) is WSDL generated by ESB for the proxy service. When I try to send the same request to the proxy service with soapUI the following error occurs:

> The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is
>   /services/test.testHttpSoap11Endpoint and the WSA Action = . If this
>   EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

Sending this request's body with ESB's proxy service testing tool I have no problem. I think it's because this tool uses WS-Addressing to send it. The request is also sent smoothly with soapUI if endpoint URL is appended by `?createRequest`. According to this [article](http://wso2.org/library/176) a cause of the problem is SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher. For some reason it doesn't recognize target operation by QName of the first child of the SOAP body element. But I can't understand why SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher screws up in my case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference among WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 and earlier versions is WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 enable Passthrough Transport (PTT) by default. PTT is used to achieve very high performance boost in WSO2 ESB you can find some numbers here http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/01/esb-performance-65.

The main problem with your use case is it expect SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher to dispatch operation name. SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher build the message and use first child's local name for dispatching this operation is considered as very costly and hence for the moment not supported in PPT.  For the time being you can send expected SOAPAction as a HTTP header to get rid of this issue. In this thread I have provided few other solutions [Error accesing published WS proxy in WSO2 ESB 4.6: EPR not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544406/error-accesing-published-ws-proxy-in-wso2-esb-4-6-epr-not-found/15556669#15556669)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sagara.  
How can I make dispatching by SOAP header or body? Should I use another transport? When I try to set "org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.NHttpGetProcessor" as httpGetProcessor in http listener settings an [error](http://pastebin.com/2pqfKKRr) occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Changing httpGetProcessor won't help here you have to change transportSender and transportReceiver configuration. You can comment out existing PTT transportSender/transportReceiver and uncomment NHTTP transportSender/transportReceiver configurations on axis2.xml file.

This is what you have on ESB 4.6.0

```
<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender">
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
</transportSender>

<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>       
    <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>      
</transportReceiver>
```

What you need is

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.NHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
    <parameter name="disableRestServiceDispatching" locked="false">true</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSender">
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

Comment: Thank you again. SOAP body based dispatching works fine with this configuration.